# Maximum Likelihood Estimator Geometric Distribution

Tags: statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around finding a likelihood function for a geometric distribution based on some measurements. We take the pmf of the flaws in an industrial process to be

$$p(x) = \theta (1-\theta)^{x} \qquad x=0,1,2,\ldots \quad \text{and}\quad 0<\theta<1.$$

Then if we have $n$ samples, of which $n_{0}$ have no flaws and $n_{2}$ have at least two flaws. I know that if these samples are independent, the likelihood should be the product of all trials, but the course notes I'm using give the likelihood function as

$$l(\theta) = \theta^{n_{0}+n_{1}}(1-\theta)^{2n-2n_{0}-n_{1}}.$$

**Am I right to think that there's something combinatoric going on here?** I've tried taking

$$l(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\theta(1-\theta)^{x},$$

but this gives (I think?)

$$l(\theta) = \theta^{n}(1-\theta)^{0\cdot n_{0} + 1 \cdot(n-n_{0}-n_{1}) + 2\cdot n_1}.$$

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The probability of an single sample having *at least* two flaws is $(1-\theta)^2$

which I think might make your likelihood function proportional to  $$\theta^{n_0}\times\theta^{n_1}(1-\theta)^{n_1} \times  (1-\theta)^{2n_2} $$ $$= \theta^{n_0+n_1}(1-\theta)^{n_1+2n_2} $$  $$= \theta^{n_0+n_1}(1-\theta)^{2n - 2n_0 -n_1} $$ 
in terms of $n, n_0,n_1$.  This is the expression you queried

Expressed in terms of $n, n_0,n_2$ it would be   $ \theta^{n-n_2}(1-\theta)^{n-n_0+n_2}$